# Python 2.7 Tkinter Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

My Tkinter code is showing no problems but When I run it Nothing Shows Up. What is Wrong?

I'M using Python 2.7. It's Supposed to be a pizzeria Game by the way

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import StringVar
import ttk
from random import randint , choice ,uniform

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Easy, Hard):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage():
    tk.Label(text = "Welcome!" , font = ("Verdana", 12)).pack()
    ttk.Button(text = "Play" , command = lambda: Window().show_frame(Play()))

class Play():
    def loop():
        q = randint(0, 10)
        p = uniform(1.50 , 10.50)
        t = uniform(.1, .9)
        p2 = p*q
        p3 = p2*t
        g = StringVar()
        ttk.Entry(textvariable=g).pack()
        ttk.Label(text = "Price Per Pizza: " + str(p) + " Amount: " + str(q) + " Tax: " + str(t))
        if g == p3 : ttk.Label(text = "Correct!")
        elif g != p3: ttk.Label(text = "Try Again.")
    loop()
    ttk.Button(text = "Play" , command = lambda: loop())

Window.mainloop
```

Comment: `Window.mainloop` is not a function call. And you should include the code in question here.

Comment: `Window.mainloop` points nowhere because there is no function called `mainloop` in your `Window` class. Please consider reading [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your post.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mwormser Window is a subclass of `Tkinter.Tk`, so there is `mainloop` method available. It is just not called as it should be, `w = Window(); w.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does nothing, since it just a reference to `mainloop` method of `Window` class

```
Window.mainloop
```

You need to create an instance of `Window` class before you call `mainloop`

```
w = Window()
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks i thought that wasn't needed it is working now.